# for json Element id = "1" , append ul 'chapter_count' times

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am fairly new to web dev and This is my first question on StackOverflow. Apologies if I didn't frame it properly.

Here is my json.

```
{
"books":
  [
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "book_cat": "OLD",
        "book_eng_name": "Book1",
        "chapter_count": "50"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "book_cat": "OLD",
        "book_eng_name": "Book2",
        "chapter_count": "40""
    }
]
```

I want to use this json with jquery to append to . First I need to filter `__id` and then append a statement to the `<ul>` "Chapter_count" times.

For instance, if I select I am searching for `_id 1` I want 50 item list that says

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
...
...
...
Chapter 50
```

I want to append to ul in the following html:

```
<html>
<title>Chapters</title>
<body>
<ul></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/
jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src='files/js/Chapter_script.js'></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src='files/js/books.json'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrote something like this but didn't work :(

```
(document).ready(function(){
  var search_id = window.location.search;
  var chapter_no = search_id.match(/\d+/g);
  $.getJSON("files/js/books.json",function(data){

    $.each(data.books, function(){
      if (this['_id'] == chapter_no ){
        for(var i = 0; i <= this['chapter_count']; i++; ){
          $("ul").append("<li>Chapter Number"+i+"</li></br>")
        }
      };

    })
  });

});
```

Where chapter_no is extracted from url with window.location.search
Sample url: http://localhost:90/chapters.html?book_id=1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also provide your HTML code where you want to append

Comment: We're here to help you, but you have to try something first. You can't just come here and say, "Here's what I want, please write the code for me". I suggest that first you go through a bunch of tutorials about how to iterate a JSON.

Comment: (document).ready(function(){
  var search_id = window.location.search;
  var chapter_no = search_id.match(/\d+/g);
  $.getJSON("files/js/books.json",function(data){

    $.each(data.books, function(){
      if (this['_id'] == chapter_no ){
        for(var i = 0; i <= this['chapter_count']; i++; ){
          $("ul").append("<li>Chapter Number"+i+"</li></br>")
        }
      };
     
    })
  });

});

@Jeremy I wrote this but this isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the below code in `$.getJSON("files/js/books.json",function(data)` function.

```
var selectedElement = $.grep(data.books, function( element, index ) {
                        if(chapter_no == element._id)
                        return element
                      });
for(var i =0 ; i<=selectedElement[0].chapter_count;i++)
{
   $("ul").append("<li>Chapter Number"+i+"</li></br>")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.

Will look more into grep.

Answer (score 0):

first your json is not valid and have syntax error i think the true one is

```
json ={ "books": [ { "_id": "1", "book_cat": "OLD", "book_eng_name": "Book1", 
    "chapter_count": "50" }, { "_id": "2", "book_cat": "OLD", 
        "book_eng_name": "Book2", "chapter_count": "40" } ]}
```

its sample js code

```
json.books.forEach(function (b){
    if(b._identer code here == "1")
    {
        for(var i =0 ; i<=b.caphter_count;i++)
        {
            //put your code here
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: So, should this go under
    $.getJSON("files/js/books.json",function(data)
right?